# E_RUNTIME_USER_STRINGTOOBIG xml pasing

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Trying to load XML through Azure Data Lake jobs I faced unbreakable issues with E_RUNTIME_USER_STRINGTOOBIG using [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats)

The thing is that XmlDomExtractor the only way to join (or rather apply) elements from inside the same XML file (One-To-Many).

```
@xml =
EXTRACT Id string,
        //...
        Products string
FROM @"/pathToXml.xml"
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlDomExtractor("contract",
      new SQL.MAP<string, string>{
      {"id", "Id"},
      //...
      // this is actually a node that may contain thousand of child node
      {"products", "Products"}
      });
```

Apply:

```
@data = SELECT c.Id,
        //....
        pp.ProductSid, 
        // ... other product properties
    FROM @prepareData AS c
    OUTER APPLY
        new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlApplier ("Products","/",new SQL.MAP<string, string>{
      {"/abc/p/s", "ProductSid"},
      //....
      }) AS pp(
            ProductSid string, 
            /*....*/
              );
```

The full version of the code is [here](https://github.com/semashkinvg/Azure.HowTos/blob/DataLake.GovermentContracts/DataLake.Samples/GovermentContracts/GovernmentContracts.DL.Jobs/XmlParsingSamples/Script_remote2.usql)

I've tried to minimize my XML node by replacing names by letter. Unfortunately, it didn't help because of thousands of the items inside (+ long names of the products) broke through the limitation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

there is no actual solution to cope with this issue so far. But I've found only two ways to get around:

The first, minimize your XML or JSON. In case of XML, check namespaces. Getting rid of them may help ( in my case it fixed most of the 'too-long' value)

The second is write your own extractor (which is not that hard).

I used both approaches and here is the implementation of my own [parser](https://github.com/semashkinvg/Azure.HowTos/tree/DataLake.GovermentContracts/DataLake.Samples/GovermentContracts/ItWasMe.Azure.DataLake.Udo). Here is the usage [example](https://github.com/semashkinvg/Azure.HowTos/blob/DataLake.GovermentContracts/DataLake.Samples/GovermentContracts/GovernmentContracts.DL.Jobs/XmlParsingSamples/Script_remote3.usql). Please, feel free to use it.

It's pretty generic and supports XPath and namespaces as well. In terms of performance, it's pretty similar to Microsoft's implementation

### Performance

During my investigation of this issue, I found that both parsers work extremely slow processing many small files.

However, making too big files (~2GBs) causes the OutOfMemory exception. My assumption here is that it happens because of files are processed as Atomic (the file isn't distributed by 250 MB chunks which are processed independently like CSV or TSV). As for my case, files size 200-250 MB is optimal

Comment: Would attribute-based XML make a difference?  It is considerably more compact.

Comment: @wBob, if you're talking about performance, unfortunately, I haven't checked it yet. Anyone who made an investigation regarding "attribute-based" can leave another answer below.